# Reference Excel Table with INSERTT INTO SELECT connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

I am using this code in Excel to export a table to an SQL Server Table

```
Sub ExportToSQLServer()
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection, rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConn As String, sSQL As String
    sConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
            "Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
            "Persist Security Info=True;" & _
            "Initial Catalog=ES_RTR_Staging;" & _
            "Data Source=sqlnode23;" & _
            "Use Procedure for Prepare=1;" & _
            "Auto Translate=True;" & _
            "Packet Size=4096;" & _
            "Use Encryption for Data=False;" & _
            "Tag with column collation when possible=False"

    cnn.Open sConn

        'Code here to set up ES_RTR_Staging table prior to import of new data (all works fine)

    '// this is where I am having a problem with correct syntax to reference a table named "tblTempFD" on
        'a sheet named "TempFcast" (both tab name and code name the same for that sheet)

    sSQL = "INSERT INTO " & sTblID & _
            " SELECT * FROM tblTempFD"
    cnn.Execute sSQL

    '// also tried
    sSQL = "INSERT INTO " & sTblID & _
            " SELECT * FROM [TempFcast$] tblTempFD"
    cnn.Execute sSQL

    '// Error is "Invalid Object Name"

End Sub
```

I cannot get the syntax right for referencing the Excel table, any help or pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`[TempFcast$]` is trying to call the evaluate function.  When you bracket an identifier like that, the object you're calling it on looks to see if it has a function with a member ID of -5 ([DISPID_EVALUATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221242(v=vs.85).aspx)).  If it finds one, it passes the contents of the brackets as a late-bound call to that function to determine what it is.

In this case, you're implicitly calling DISPID_EVALUATE on the Worksheet (if it's in a `Worksheet` module), the Workbook (if it's in `ThisWorkbook`), or `Excel.Application` if it's in a standard module.

A Worksheet actually *does* have a DISPID_EVALUATE member that maps to the `Evaluate` function.  If your code is in a Worksheet module, it's the equivalent to:

```vb
Me.Evaluate("TempFcast$")
```

This is a garbage input for `Worksheet.Evaluate`, so you get a runtime error 2015.

`Excel.Workbook` - doesn't have a DISPID_EVALUATE member, so it falls back to the `Application` object.  This means it is equivalent to:

```vb
Application.Evaluate("TempFcast$")
```

This is also garbage input for for `Application.Evaluate`, which actually passes the call to `ActiveSheet.Evaluate("TempFcast$")`.

So, long story short, don't use foreign call (bracketed) syntax in Excel unless you intend to call `.Evaluate`. Even if you do intend to call `.Evaluate`, you should call `.Evaluate` instead for this very reason.  The solution is to just remove the brackets and explicitly use the `Name` properties.

Comment: Thanks for reply, not sure it is as straight forward as that because I just edited the code above because that was definitely wrong, the Excel Table reference should have been within the sSQL quotes, not appended with &.